# Routees referring to Router

Tags: scala, routes, akka

If I use the code below (from http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/routing.html), how do the `routees` refer to/communicate with `router2` (without using `sender()`), as the `context.parent` does not work?

```
val actor1 = system.actorOf(Props[ExampleActor1])
val actor2 = system.actorOf(Props[ExampleActor1])
val actor3 = system.actorOf(Props[ExampleActor1])
val routees = Vector[ActorRef](actor1, actor2, actor3)
val router2 = system.actorOf(Props[ExampleActor1].withRouter(
RoundRobinRouter(routees = routees)))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "refer to/communicate with".  Why would a routee need to communicate with its router parent explicitly?

Comment: @cmbaxter For its messages to reach other `Actor`s 'over' the Router (there is a word for that I cannot find it).

Answer (score 1):

As you've currently written it, they can't.  You'll have to pass the router's `ActorRef` to the routees explicitly.

The other option is the let the router create its routees as then the routees' `context.parent` will refer to the router.

Comment: How can your second solution be realizable as my `Actor`s being of different kinds I have to create them separately? There is something I do not understand here.

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea.  Why do your routees need to be of different types?

Comment: My `actor`s are part of a greater body, an entity. My `actor`s have each different functions in that body and have to communicate together. I thought they could do so through a `router`.

Comment: Generally that's not the use case for a router.  Routers are typically used for concurrency when you want to dispatch different pieces of work to actors of the *same* type.

Comment: Ok. So what I should do if not using a `router`?

Comment: That really comes down to your use case, there's no general answer.

Comment: So I suppose in my case, it is better to create a parent `actor` with children of different types.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a routee to be able to communicate with other routees over the router then you could send the router (introduce it) into the routees as a message after everything is created.  From there, you can Broadcast a message over the router to get it to all routees, but keep in mind that the broadcasting routee will also receive the same message.  Something like this:

```
object MyActor{
  case class SetParent(ref:ActorRef)
  case class OtherMessage(s:String)
} 

class MyActor extends Actor{
  import MyActor._

  def receive = myReceive()

  def myReceive(parentOpt:Option[ActorRef] = None):Receive = {
    case SetParent(parent) => context.become(myReceive(Some(parent)))
    case OtherMessage(msg) => println(s"Got other message: $msg")
    case someOtherMsg => 
      parentOpt foreach (parent => Broadcast(OtherMessage("hello world")))
  }
}
```

Then, your actor creation logic looks like this:

```
val actor1 = system.actorOf(Props[ExampleActor1])
val actor2 = system.actorOf(Props[ExampleActor1])
val actor3 = system.actorOf(Props[ExampleActor1])
val routees = Vector[ActorRef](actor1, actor2, actor3)
val router2 = system.actorOf(Props[ExampleActor1].withRouter(
  RoundRobinRouter(routees = routees)))
routees foreach (r => r ! SetParent(router))
```

Comment: I feel you are raising something here. It does not seem like the thing I am trying to do with this is stuff you would naturally try... Would you please explain why `routees` should not communicate with the `router`? The message exchanges have to be bidirectional.

Comment: How about you describe to me why you need to do it?  I have never had a need to do this in years of programing in Akka, but that doesn't mean there are not reasons.

Comment: My architecture features three layers of `actor`s: 1) the first figuring the router, 2) the second figuring functional `actor`s, mastering 3) the third layer's workers. Once the work delegated to the workers is completed, their master `actor`, their functional parent `actor`needs to communicate to another functional `actor` the results of the computing. In this way, my functional `agent` needs to communicate directly with the `router` to reach its pair.