# No router actor broadcasting unknown message to children

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to forward a message to each child of an actor.

I have two problems here:

1. trying to route any `message` to the children without knowing what message it is
2. access all the children at once.

So I am merely trying to have my actor do a router job but without being one... I have formerly asked a question which concluded that I could not use a `router`, see: [Routees referring to Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384995/routees-referring-to-router/25386855?noredirect=1#comment39679387_25386855).

What I am looking for is a way to spare me the boring writing of a message for each type and each child.
Is there a way to evade this work? With a method? I thought `children` (http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/actor/ActorContext.html) would work but it does not.

Comment: The `.children` method on the context should work just fine provided those actors are truly children of that actor.  Not sure why `.children` won't work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why something like this won't work for you:

```
class ParentRouter extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case message =>
      context.children foreach (_.forward(message))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Does this message is a defined message or is it an unknown message? I.e. can I forward a message not knowing what it is?

Comment: You can forward any message you want.  Because there is no message "interface" to an Actor (one that would tell you what kinds of messages that Actor handles) there is always the chance that the Actor might not handle that message though.

Comment: Would this work ? case fff @ _ => context.children foreach (_.forward(fff))

Comment: @wipman, yes, but it's unnecessary.  Because I'm not qualifying `message` by giving it a type then it basically is acting as the `_` and gives me a variable binding to boot.

Comment: Is there any way to forward a message to a huge set of `children` without using `context`?

Comment: @wipman, if you create the children up front and assign their refs to say a List of ActorRefs then you could skip using context.children if this list of children is static.  If the amount of children to send to is always in flux, using context.children is best as you don't have to write the logic to constantly keep track of this changing list.